# What is a Corruption Test?

Tags: the-one-ring, corruption

The introductory adventure for *The One Ring: Adventures Over the Edge of the Wild* (in the back of the Loremaster's book) says on page 130 that players must pass a Corruption Test for every day that they are in Mirkwood or gain a Shadow point. However, a "Corruption Test" isn't in the index of the Adventurer's Book and I can't find it elsewhere (I figured it'd be in Chapter 5: Adventuring Mechanics, but I can't find it there or anywhere else).

So how does one make a Corruption Test? Is this actually a mechanic or is it some sort of misprint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A **Corruption test** is made using the Feat die plus a number of Success
>   dice equal to the character's Wisdom rating.

–p.28, The One Ring, **Loremaster's Book**

For further details about mechanics (Target Numbers etc), causes and effects and consequences see p.28 and p.56+ in the **TOR LB**.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think to look for it in the Loremaster's Book. This definitely seems like a mechanic that ought to be in the Adventurer's Book.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with that. In general, these "darker" aspects of the game (and their workings) and the characters are better left a semi-secret in the LM's hands. Sure, YMMV. :)

Comment: I think the difference is that, unlike Encounters or Journey obstacles, it's the *players* who are expected to roll the dice for a Corruption test, so it makes sense that their book would have rules for how to do that. Besides, it sounds to me that Corruption Tests are supposed to come up once per game session or so, making it odd that only the GM would know about such an important rule. Sure, the players may not be privy to the effects, but they should at least know how to make a roll.

Comment: Right, I have to admit that you also have some good points there... :)

Comment: @Thunderforge I think the reason that this appears in the LM book is because the process of corruption is something more than a few rolls. A LM is expected to guide the player and the story in this process.

Comment: @Flamma It looks to me like there is only one roll, the one described in this post. The TN of the task, as well as how many points get lost is up to the LM (understandably), but then the players keep track of the loss; that seems to be all there is. I'd prefer something in the Adventurer's Guide saying: Beware of Corruption. Here's how you make a Corruption Test. If the LM says you take Shadow Points, here's how you record it on your Character sheet.

Comment: @Thunderforge I see that would be helpful. But if you are looking the logic of it being on the LM book is that: corruption is much more than the rolls, the LM, for instance is the one who say when the character goes mad. It needs a whole chapter and the developer thought that chapter would serve better the LM.

Comment: You're right, it does need a bigger description for the effects and that's better suited for the Loremaster Book. Ultimately, I'd like to see it in both with the limited rules that players need to know in the Adventurer's Guide and the full rules in the Loremaster's Book. Hopefully Cubicle 7 sees my suggestion :-)

Comment: @Thunderforge Players roll most of the dice in travel. Corruption, however, is always an LM's call, not a mechanical default.